# Question about proof of positive roots under reflection

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, coxeter-groups, root-systems

Since I did not receive a lot of responses on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485893/question-about-proof-of-positive-roots-under-reflection)
I would like to repost this question here.

Let $(W, S)$ be a finite Coxeter system. Furthermore, let $V$ be a real vector space with a (finite) basis $\{ \alpha_s | s \in S \}$.

For every $s \in S$ one can define the reflection $\sigma_s : V \to V, v \mapsto v - 2 B(v, \alpha_s) \alpha_s $ where $B$ is the bilinear form defined by $B(\alpha_s, \alpha_t ) = - \cos(\frac{\pi}{m(s,t)})$.

There also exists a unique group homomorphism$\sigma : W \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ such that $\sigma(s) = \sigma_s$, the so-called geometric representation of $(W,S)$. 
From now on we denote $\sigma(w) (v)$ for $v \in V, w \in W$ by just $w(v)$.

Now let $\Phi = \{w(\alpha_s) | w \in W, s \in S\} $ be the set of all roots and $\Pi = \{ v \in \Phi | v = \sum_{t \in S} c_t \alpha_t, c_t \geq 0 \forall t \in S\} $  the system of positive roots. Now consider $\alpha_s \in V$ for $s \in S$, a so-called simple root.

***At this moment I am dealing with the proof of*** $s(\Pi \setminus \{ \alpha_s \}) = \Pi \setminus \{ \alpha_s \}$.

Let $\alpha \in \Pi \setminus \{ \alpha_s \}$. Then one can write $\alpha = \sum_{t \in S} c_t \alpha_t$ where the coefficients are non-negative and there exists a $t_0 \in S$ with $c_{t_0} > 0$.

Applying $s$ leads to $s(\alpha) = \sum_{t \neq s} c_t \alpha_t + \mu \alpha_s$ where I calculated $\mu = - c_s + 2 \sum_{t \neq s} c_t \cos(\frac{\pi}{m(s,t)}) $. Note that the cosines are non-negative since $m(s,t) \geq 2$ for $t \neq s$.

But I don't really know why $\mu \geq 0$ though since the $-c_s \leq 0$ could mess everything up.

It drives me insane that I could not find an answer yet. Could someone tell me why it still works? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is a very old textbook result, easily proved at an appropriate early place in the development.      So it doesn't seem to qualify as research-level at all.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $B(\alpha,\alpha_s)\leq 0$ for every $\alpha\in\Pi$.  Then if $\alpha=\sum_{t\neq s}c_t\alpha_t+c_s\alpha_s$, we have 
\begin{align*}
B(\alpha,\alpha_s)= & \sum_{t\neq s}c_tB(\alpha_t,\alpha_s)+c_sB(\alpha_s,\alpha_s)\\
=& -\sum_{t\neq s}c_t\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m(s,t)}\right)+c_s\\
& \leq 0
\end{align*}
This should give you what you need.

Comment: Thank you, now I almost have it! Could you please only give me a little hint how to prove that $B(\alpha, \alpha_s) \leq 0$?

Comment: You say it yourself:  Note that cosines are non-negative since $m(s,t)\geq 2$ for $t\neq s$ :-)

Comment: I'm really sorry because I really tried to thought about your remark for a while but I still can't see it. What makes it impossible for $c_s$ to be greater than $\sum_{t\neq s}c_t\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m(s,t)}\right)$ in your inequality?